# Reference Scriptable Object property in Unity3d Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am trying to build out some content for a strategy game I'm building in Unity3d.  I am currently using Scriptable Objects to create assets, however I'm having an issue getting exactly what I would like when it comes to linking the assets.

Let me give a proper example with some code.  Lets say I have a building that accepts resources.  So I might have my building SCO to look like:

```
public class buildingSCO : ScriptableObject {
    public string Name;
    public string ID;
    public string Res;
}
```

And my resource SCO would look like:

```
public class resourceSCO : ScriptableObject {
    public string Name;
    public string ID;
}
```

So when I create the asset for the building I would enter the ID of the resource by hand (or copy/paste).  But my concern is that as I create more and more assets I'll start to make errors.  What I'd like is to be able to open an object selector and just select the resource asset I want the id of.

Comment: is there a chnce you could edit and shorten your question?  eg totally eliminate the first 3 sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Unity will create copies and copies of your SCOs. Just reference them the way Unity intends you to, and you will be fine.

```
public class buildingSCO : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Name;
    public string ID;
    public resourceSco Res;
}
```

First rule of optimization: don't optimize.

If you really, **really** need to work with Ids and lookups, you can do that by creating a Custom Inspector.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(buildingSCO))]
public class BuildingSCOInspector : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        buildingSCO building = target as buildingSCO;

        building.Name = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Name", building.Name);
        building.ID = EditorGUILayout.TextField("ID", building.ID); // or whatever

        // this only shows currently selected resourceSCO.ID
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Res (current)", building.Res);

        // this allows selection of another resourceSCO
        resourceSCO resource = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Res", null, typeof(resourceSCO), false) as resourceSCO;
        if (resource != null)
        {
            building.Res = resource.ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to check your custom editor, I think it might be what I was looking for.  I just re-read my question and I can see where you thought I was concerned about the multiple copies.  I will try to clear the question up.

Comment: The custom editor is exactly what I was looking for.  There were some issues with code (like the OnInspectorGUI signature needs to be public override), so I'll make a quick edit to what you posted.  This will help me ensure I don't enter an Id incorrectly.